# Add numbers from html <form> drop-down

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 3 different drop-down menus in a HTML form and a php variable that needs to be calculated depending on the form selection (values)

```
    <form>
        <select name="menu1">
            <option value="5">Option 1</option>
            <option value="10">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <select name="menu2">
            <option value="12">Option 1</option>
            <option value="24">Option 2</option>
            <option value="36">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="menu3">
            <option value="50">Option 1</option>
            <option value="100">Option 2</option>
            <option value="200">Option 3</option>
            <option value="0">Option 4</option>
        </select>
    </form>


$total = total of selected options
```

What im trying to achieve is when an option is selected the $total to be changed depending on the selection.

**Example:**

```
If selected MENU1/OPTION1 (5)  MENU2/OPTION3 (24) MENU3/OPTION1 (50)
$total = 79
```

also `$total` should be visible all the time, so when MENU1/OPTION1 (5) is selected, user should see $total = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, assuming you're using POST, shouldn't be different with GET, just change all the `$_POST`s to `$_GET`s

```
if(isset($_POST['menu1'])){
   $total=intval($_POST['menu1'])+intval($_POST['menu2'])+intval($_POST['menu3']);
}
```

EDIT: I think I misread the question. You want dynamic updating of the form values. That's impossible with PHP unless you want to use AJAX, and that seems like a waste of time when you could do it with Javascript

For Javascript, you can do it like this:

```
function isNumeric(num) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}
var total=document.forms[0]["menu1"].value+document.forms[0]["menu2"].value+document.forms[0]["menu3"].value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i think it will be best to use the javascript, but can you tell me how to dispaly the total?
Thanks again!

Comment: You would have to use something like `innerHTML` for that. You can do this with something like: `document.getElementById("totaldisplay").innerHTML=total;`